# I'm trying to understand how to make 2 classes hover at same time

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
.ellenon {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 350px;
  height:350px;
  background-image: url("https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp5609581.jpg");
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  color:white;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.ellenon :where(h1, p) {
  line-height:1.5em;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.ellenon:hover {
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}

.ellenon h1:hover {
  transform: translate(0px, -20px);
  color:transparent;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.ellenon p:hover {
   transform: translate(0px, 20px);
  color:transparent;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.ellenon2:hover {
  transform: translate(0px, -20px);
  color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="ellenon"><a href="https://codepen.io/" class="ellenon2"><h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1> <p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</p></a></div>
```

Hello there, I am trying to create a simple CSS animation as you can see in my code. However, I can't understand how to execute both hovers once the user hovers over the external div. Is this possible with raw CSS or JS is needed?

Thanks

Comment: `.ellenon:hover h1 {...}`, `.ellenon:hover p {...}` ...?

Comment: give the elements the same classname and then apply your styling with `elementname:hover {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the `.outer:hover` and `.outer:hover .inner` so both will change when the outer is hovered

```css
.outer{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:orange;
}
.inner{
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color:blue;
}
.outer:hover{
  background-color:green;
}
.outer:hover .inner{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now _this_ is how you write a minimal reproducible example! Down to the point, no fluff and stars and storylines to follow - focused on the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

use `.one:hover .two` . if you have hover on .one you change .two